# Optimising latitude and longitude selection query

Tags: mysql, innodb, partitioning, spatial

I have table as follows the schema below.

```
CREATE TABLE `gdata` ( 
`alarmTypeID` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
`fleetID` smallint(11) NOT NULL, 
`fleetGroupID` smallint(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`fleetSubGroupID` smallint(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`deviceID` mediumint(11) NOT NULL, 
`vehicleID` mediumint(11) NOT NULL, 
`gDateTime` datetime NOT NULL, 
`insertDateTime` datetime NOT NULL, 
`latitude` float NOT NULL, 
`longitude` float NOT NULL, 
`speed` smallint(11) NOT NULL, 
(see full text) 
ALTER TABLE `gdata` 
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`vehicleID`,`gDateTime`,`alarmTypeID`), 
ADD KEY `gDateTime` (`gDateTime`), 
ADD KEY `fleetID` (`fleetID`,`vehicleID`,`gDateTime`); 
COMMIT;
```

My issue now is that I can run a query as below `EXPLAIN select vehicleID,latitude,longitude from gdata where  gDateTime between '2017-07-03 00:00:00' and '2017-07-04 00:00:00'`
and the results of the explains is

```
1   SIMPLE  gdata       range   gDateTime   gDateTime   5       1251    100.00  Using index condition
```

I have the following function which works to test if the a latitude and longitude is withing a rectangle.

```
DELIMITER $$
--
-- Functions
--
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
    FUNCTION `geoProcessor`(pt POINT, mp MULTIPOLYGON)
        RETURNS int(1)
        DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 

DECLARE str, xy TEXT; 
DECLARE x, y, p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y, m, xinters DECIMAL(16, 13) DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE p, pb, pe INT DEFAULT 0; 

SELECT MBRWithin(pt, mp) INTO p; 
IF p != 1 OR ISNULL(p) THEN 
RETURN p; 
END IF; 

SELECT X(pt), Y(pt), ASTEXT(mp) INTO x, y, str; 
SET str = REPLACE(str, 'POLYGON((',''); 
SET str = REPLACE(str, '))', ''); 
SET str = CONCAT(str, ','); 

SET pb = 1; 
SET pe = LOCATE(',', str); 
SET xy = SUBSTRING(str, pb, pe - pb); 
SET p = INSTR(xy, ' '); 
SET p1x = SUBSTRING(xy, 1, p - 1); 
SET p1y = SUBSTRING(xy, p + 1); 
SET str = CONCAT(str, xy, ','); 

WHILE pe > 0 DO 
SET xy = SUBSTRING(str, pb, pe - pb); 
SET p = INSTR(xy, ' '); 
SET p2x = SUBSTRING(xy, 1, p - 1); 
SET p2y = SUBSTRING(xy, p + 1); 
IF p1y < p2y THEN SET m = p1y; ELSE SET m = p2y; END IF; 
IF y > m THEN 
IF p1y > p2y THEN SET m = p1y; ELSE SET m = p2y; END IF; 
IF y <= m THEN 
IF p1x > p2x THEN SET m = p1x; ELSE SET m = p2x; END IF; 
IF x <= m THEN 
IF p1y != p2y THEN 
SET xinters = (y - p1y) * (p2x - p1x) / (p2y - p1y) + p1x; 
END IF; 
IF p1x = p2x OR x <= xinters THEN 
SET counter = counter + 1; 
END IF; 
END IF; 
END IF; 
END IF; 
SET p1x = p2x; 
SET p1y = p2y; 
SET pb = pe + 1; 
SET pe = LOCATE(',', str, pb); 
END WHILE; 

RETURN counter % 2; 

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

My issue now I want to find out which vehicle is within a rectangle within a time range value. I have to run two separate queries to first run the first queries get the lat, long value then test if its within the rectangle using the second query. How to opmtimise this?

Comment: The first `SELECT` does not mention the bounding box, augment it to do so.  The `FUNCTION` talks about one point in one polygon, not multiple points in a 'rectangle'.  Bottom line:  What is the real question?

Comment: @RickJames the question is within a time range which vehicles were within a polygon boundary

Answer (score 3):

To find which vehicle(s) are in a specific 'rectangle' ("bounding box") during a particular day,

```
SELECT ...
    FROM gdata
    WHERE gDateTime >= '2017-07-03'
      AND gDateTime  < '2017-07-03' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
      AND latitude > 34.567
      AND latitude < 35.678
      AND longitude > 123.456
      AND longitude < 124.567;
```

The optimizer cannot do a perfect job of optimizing the query, but you can give it 3 choices and hope that it picks the best:

```
INDEX(gDateTime),
INDEX(latitude),
INDEX(longitude)
```

Since each column is used in a "range", there is no advantage in putting two columns in a single index.  (Only the first column will be used.)

Or, with SPATIAL index...

If it is a polygon, not a simple rectangle, then something like

```
SELECT ...
    FROM gdata
    WHERE gDateTime >= '2017-07-03'
      AND gDateTime  < '2017-07-03' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
      AND MBRWithin(pt, ...);
```

with

- pt being an extra column containing a POINT
- SPATIAL(pt)
- the '...' being a pre-calculated polygon from somewhere else

Do not call your FUNCTION in the `WHERE` clause; that will be terribly inefficient.

Since you only want a list of `vehicleID`, not all the locations, this is probably better:

```
SELECT DISTINCT vehicleID
    FROM gdata
    WHERE ...
```

`DISTINCT` is sort of a degenerate case of `GROUP BY`.  I prefer to use `DISTINCT` in this situation since it makes it clearer what is going on.

**Partitioning?**

`PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(gDateTime))` with 20-50 partitions may help performance, especially if the table will be billions of rows long.  The partitioning would narrow the focus to one (maybe more) partition, then do the spatial (or lat/lng) lookup within just that partition.

Also, partitioning is an excellent way to purge 'old' data.

Use cases 1 and 2 of [*my partition blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) discuss those two ideas.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61783/discussion-on-answer-by-rick-james-optimising-latitude-and-longitude-selection-q).

Answer (score 3):

Accidentally I have the DB with table that contain 50+ million of NMEA rows in it. The table have the complex index (timestamp, lat, lon). Simple query has been launched:

```
SELECT DISTINCT vehicle_id
  FROM nmea 
 WHERE ts  BETWEEN '2016-05-10' AND '2016-05-11'
   AND lat BETWEEN 50.00 AND 50.20
   AND lon BETWEEN 30.00 AND 30.20
;
```

So I've get:

```
+------------+
| vehicle_id |
+------------+
|      12787 |
|       3123 |
|       9734 |
|      11201 |
|       7241 |
|      21002 |
|       4509 |
+------------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

`EXPLAIN` shows the next (a bit trimmed):

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------+------------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys    | key        | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------+------------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | w     | range | ...ts_lat_lon... | ts_lat_lon | 12      | NULL | 57362 | Using index condition; Using temporary |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------+------------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here we can see that there is no penalties for using `BETWEEN`s with proper index.

Here is the suggestion: lat-lon coordinates have the anomaly near to the prime meridian. Every rectangle dissected by it should be splitted into two different rectangles to the left and to the right of PM and checked separately.

Comment: quite difficult for me to fix the data to be near the prime meridian as this data is a gps data from vehicles travelling different location in a country

Comment: I might be having data in few billion for one month but I know I will be doing partitioning but will be able to work on huge sum of data ?

Comment: My data is of GPS tracking too. But here in Europe we always have to remember  about prime meridian.

Comment: here without the prime meridian what idea will you suggest looks like i go to look into the spatial index have you tried that on mysql innodb?

Comment: Proposed select with `BETWEEN`s in conjunction with proper index is fast and reliable. I've developed backend for GPS tracking for three years and there is no visible benefits of using geospatial data types in `mysql`.

Comment: yes I have index for the gdatetime between the issue is after that the next step to find if the extracted latitude and longitude fitting in a specific polygon? That is challenge now. I am anticipating around 1billion plus row data in a month will Mysql able to handle that many inserts and scale in your opinion?

Comment: @user8012596 You need not the separate index for the single column `gDateTime` but complex multicolumn index that include gDateTime AND coordinates.

Comment: any idea how to achieve the index you suggested?

Answer (score 3):

> I have the following function which works to test if the a latitude and longitude is withing a rectangle.

**NOOOOO**. You're recreating the wheel.

## Use geospatial

First we need to add a column, and then we populate it.

```
ALTER TABLE geom ADD pt POINT;

UPDATE geom
  SET pt = point(longitude, latitude);

ALTER TABLE geom DROP COLUMN latitude, DROP COLUMN longitude;
```

We dropped the old columns because they're redundant at this point. You can access what was the longitude and latitude by using `ST_X(pt)`, and `ST_Y(pt)` respectively.

Then we add the index.

```
ALTER TABLE geom ADD SPATIAL INDEX(g);
```

Now, [we can use an indexable operation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-relation-functions-mysql-specific.html) with [ST_MakeEnvelope](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-makeenvelope)

```
SELECT *
FROM geom
WHERE MBRContains(
  ST_MakeEnvelope(Point(x1,y1),Point(x2,y2)),
  pt
);
```

See an [example of the above working on MySQL 5.7 on RexTester](http://rextester.com/JSYISA81495).

Click [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-function-reference.html) for a list of [MySQL's Spatial Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-function-reference.html) which you can now use with the new column. When speaking of GIS, I always suggest MySQL users [upgrade to a better database. =)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64627/discussion-on-answer-by-evan-carroll-optimising-latitude-and-longitude-selection).